# Why doesn't unsigned typeof(var) work? const typeof(x) works fine, so why not?

Tags: c, gcc, casting, unsigned, typeof

In a macro I would want to make the value the same width, however unsigned. So, a natural `unsigned typeof(x)` came to mind. However, it doesn't compile:

```
/home/guest/mc.c: In function ‘main’:
/home/guest/mc.c:14:36: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘typeof’
   14 |                         *((unsigned typeof(minus)*)&minus));
```

I wonder why it is so? Maybe I'm doing something wrong? Can I somehow add `unsigned` to the type of a variable?

PS. I've noted, that similar cast adding `const` works OK:

```
#define add_const(x) ((const typeof(x))(x))
```

Also, adding `*` to create a pointer type also works OK.

Comment: `unsigned typeof(x)` --> `typeof(unsigned x)`

Comment: @DavidRanieri: But `x` is a variable, not a type. What would just prepending `myvar` with `unsigned` do?

Comment: `typeof` is not C, it is a compiler extension. `unsigned` is very different from `const` and `*`, look at how they work with typedef names (hint: exactly as with `typeof`).

Comment: I'm assuming this post is referring to the GCC extension `typeof`, and have changed the tags. Please clarify which compiler you are using when discussing specific extensions to the C language.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.: `typeof` is C per C 2018 4 7, which effectively defines all extensions of conforming compilers to be conforming code. C is not designed to be like Java in which programs should be universally portable to different implementations. It is designed for implementations to be portable to different systems and circumstances. That is why it allows flexibility in the width of `int` and so many other options. Extensions are a normal, expected, and desired part of C. C provides a base language that people can program in comfortably while also using extensions useful for their needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental reason why `unsigned typeof(x)` doesn't work but `const typeof(x)` does is that `unsigned` and `const` are two different syntax components.  `unsigned` it a type specifier, while `const` is a type qualifier.

The list of type specifiers (note that a bare `unsigned` is syntactically equivalent to `unsigned int`:

> [**6.7.2 Type
> specifiers**](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2)
>
> [1.](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2p1) **Syntax**
>
> ```
>       type-specifier:
>              void
>              char
>              short
>              int
>              long
>              float
>              double
>              signed
>              unsigned
>              _Bool
>              _Complex
>              atomic-type-specifier
>              struct-or-union-specifier
>              enum-specifier
>              typedef-name
> ```
>
> [2.](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2p2) **Constraints**
>
> ...
>
> - unsigned, or unsigned int

So `unsigned typeof(x)` is the equivalent of `unsigned int typeof(x)`.

`const` is a type qualifier:

> [**6.7.3 Type qualifiers**](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2)
>
> [1.](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2p1) **Syntax**
>
> ```
>       type-qualifier:
>              const
>              restrict
>              volatile
>              _Atomic
> ```

`const char` is proper C code, assuming `x` is a `char`.  `unsigned int char` is not proper C code.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the only way is to enumerate all "interesting" types in a generic selection.

```
#define to_unsigned(x) _Generic((x),     \
                char: (unsigned char     )(x),     \
         signed char: (unsigned char     )(x),     \
                 int: (unsigned int      )(x),     \
               short: (unsigned short    )(x),     \
                long: (unsigned long     )(x),     \
           long long: (unsigned long long)(x),     \
             default: x)

short a;
typeof(to_unsigned(a)) ua;
```

This is not portable because implementations can provide more integral types. However `typeof` by itself is specific to gcc. Since gcc seems to provide all other standard integral types (`size_t`, `uint8_t` etc) as typedef names and not separate distinct types, these cases should cover everything.

Comment: If we assume there is no padding, `#define to_unsigned(x) ((uintmax_t) (x) & ((uintmax_t) 2 << sizeof (x) * CHAR_BIT - 1) - 1)` should produce the desired value, although not always in the desired type. (Note that `2 << bits-1` is used to avoid shifting by the full number of bits in the type, which would be undefined if the type were `uintmax_t`.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil but we need a type, not a value.

Comment: The first sentence of the question says they want a value of the desired width. That is ambiguous since values are abstract things without width, and types have widths. But getting the desired value has practical uses, whereas getting a particular type is not greatly useful as the right value will serve in many places regardless of having a wider type. So I would bet on the value being the actual goal rather than the type.

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't unsigned typeof(var) work? const typeof(x) works fine, so why not?

Per [clause 6.7 of the GCC 10.2 documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/Typeof.html#Typeof):

> A `typeof` construct can be used anywhere a typedef name can be used.

In the C grammar for declarations specified in C 2018 6.7, the declaration specifiers are partitioned into classes:

- Storage-class specifiers, like `static` and `extern`.
- Type specifiers, like `int` and `float`.
- Type qualifiers, like `const` and `volatile`.
- Function specifiers, like `inline`.
- Alignment specifiers, like `_Alignas(4)`.

Clause 6.7.2 shows that a *typedef-name* is a type specifier. Paragraph 2 specifies the ways they may be used. It gives a list of permissible combinations, including:

- `int`, `signed`, or `signed int`
- `unsigned`, or `unsigned int`
- typedef name

Thus, `unsigned` can be used only in the particular combinations shown in this list, such as `unsigned long long`. A typedef name is shown as an item by itself, without `unsigned`. So it cannot be used with `unsigned`.

In contrast, `const` is a qualifier, which is a different kind of specifier, and the other clauses of 6.7 allow different kinds of specifiers to be mixed (with some additional restrictions that are not relevant here, such as having at most one storage-class specifier).